# About reference and array, is this a PHP/Zend bug?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I think the three assigtments should be equal for $a, the the dump value confuse me.

```
$a['x']=1;
$b=&$a['x'];  //dump $a['x']=2
//$b=$a['x']; //dump $a['x']=1
//$b=&$a;     //dump $a['x']=1
$c=$a;
$c['x']=2;
var_dump($a['x']);
```

Is this a PHP bug, Will it be fix in PHP7 ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What's the dump value?

Comment: Is this homework or so? Was just asked yesterday.

Comment: @Rizier123  for: $b=&$a['x'], I know $b is a reference now, but I think $a['x'] is NOT a reference, is it true?

Comment: @lovespring `$b` and `$a["x"]` point to the same value. Take a look into the dupe there is everything explained.

Comment: @Rizier123 Because $a["x"] is not a reference, for a normal assign: $c=$a, PHP SHOULD copy an entiry $a to $c, for $a['x'], PHP should copy it's value, not it's "reference" or "address pointer"

Comment: See the dupe there is 1. the link to the manual where this behaviour is documented 2. It's explained what it actually means.